# Can't enable 3rd monitor after installing ATI proprietary drivers

Tags: unity, ati, multiple-monitors, display

So, after hearing how Ubuntu 11.10 was supposed to have improved support for multiple monitors, I had to re-install again and give it a try.

I always found Ubuntu gets more done faster related to productivity than windows does, among other things, though video games and the adobe creativity suite prevent me from deleting my windows install altogether.

I had given up trying to work with Ubuntu because of it's lack of multi-monitor support, so now that it has improved...

And it has improved. Only seconds after installation, I had full resolution running on all 3 monitors across a single desktop, and each monitor even has a top bar! The performance left something to be desired, however, and it eventually irritated me enough to try to get the proprietary drivers working.

All 3 monitors working was a surprise, as I am using 1 DVI connection, 1 VGA connection, and 1 HDMI connection on a HD6850. In windows, to enable a third monitor, one of the monitors must be attached through the display port. Thank you for whoever hacked that one.

The problem is, now that I installed the proprietary drivers, I cannot enable my third monitor anymore. AMD CCC gives me an error saying it doesn't know why but it can't be enabled, and something about possible not enough video memory (though its a 1gb card).

Does anyone know if there is some kind of tweak I can perform to get the third monitor working again? I know there are a lot of parameters that can be thrown with aticonfig, though none I have found seemed relevant.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I figured out that the default driver is the open source radeon driver, which as it turns out seems to work much better than the proprietary at the moment. Except for ATI's control panel, the open source driver suffices. Search Ubuntu Software Center for 3D Acceleration settings, this helped me with my performance issues.

Comment: Huh.  I'm also surprised that you could do 1 VGA, 1 DVI, and 1 HDMI.  I was under the impression that at least two had to be DisplayPort monitors.  Maybe the DVI and HDMI monitors can be driven with the exact same clocks, though?

Answer (score 2):

OP answered this question as a comment

> I figured out that the default driver is the open source radeon driver, which as it turns out seems to work much better than the proprietary at the moment. Except for ATI's control panel, the open source driver suffices. Search Ubuntu Software Center for 3D Acceleration settings, this helped me with my performance issues.